# Emacs ENSIME cannot find dependency

Tags: scala, emacs, ensime

I'm pretty new with both Scala and ENSIME. I have a project and the first setup is ok with ENSIME that seems to work fine (auto-completion working, jump to definition working, error highlighting working, etc.). Anyway I've added a dependency in `build.sbt` (in particular I've added `circe`). ENSIME in Emacs keeps complaining `object circe is not a member of package io`.

I initially recompile the project in a separate shell. Nothing changed. After that I tried to recompile the project from Emacs with `C-c C-b c`. Nothing changed again.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to re-generate the ensime configuration if you change anything in your .sbt files. Run `sbt ensimeConfig` in your project folder and restart Ensime inside Emacs.